# Do choices in other episodes of The Walking Dead affect gameplay/story in 400 Days?

Tags: xbox-360, the-walking-dead-season-one

Without going into spoilers, can I get confirmation that the choices made in previous episodes of The Walking Dead affect gameply/story in the DLC "400 days"?

The FAQ on telltale says that it does:

> Yes. 400 Days will check to see if you have a Season 1 save file. The
>   decisions you made in Season 1 will have an effect on your 400 Days
>   experience. And yes…choices made in 400 Days will resonate in Season
>   2.

For some reason though, I didn't see ANYTHING related my prior experience/choices... and I confirmed that my save file was intact (XBOX 360).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Russell's Story...

> When you jump off the road to hide, you will be hiding next to Doug or Carly's corpse, depending on which character you chose to save in Episode 1.  This character survives until they are killed on the roadside by Lily in Episode 3.

In Shel's Story...

> Vernon's cancer survival group from Episode 4 is referenced.  The boat being stolen is also referenced.

Without hovering over the spoilers, I can tell you that the decisions you made as Lee will influence background details of stories in *400 days*, but they don't really weigh heavily on the story.

Comment: One side note, as you know data from Season 1 Episodes 1-5 carry over into 400 days. Well keep in mind if you plan on playing Season 2, that there will be decisions made from all of season 1 (including 400 days) that will affect the story in different ways.  In 400 days they re all also around the Georgia area, so it's pretty close to the same areas Clemintine and everyone else was...which means they could be very closely related in season 2.