# What decisions affect season 2?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one, the-walking-dead-season-two

I actually have two base questions.

1. What decisions in Season 1, Episodes 1 through 5, affect 400 days, and in what ways?
2. What decisions from Season 1, and 400 days affect Season 2 Episode 1?

Comment: Only the 1st episode of season 2 was released, until they are all released this is speculation about future games, which is not something we do. You can re-scope your question to ask about episode 1 exclusively.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123590/do-choices-in-other-episodes-of-the-walking-dead-affect-gameplay-story-in-400-da/123591#123591

Comment: The question has been edited, and should now be "on-topic" per the rules of Arqade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see the duplicate question.  So to answer my own question, look here:
[Do choices in other episodes of The Walking Dead affect gameplay/story in 400 Days?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123590/do-choices-in-other-episodes-of-the-walking-dead-affect-gameplay-story-in-400-da/123591#123591)

The answer gives very specific details.